# How do i return the url (without domain name) in the Opencart header?

Tags: templates, url, header, return, opencart

In my opencart multistore, to prevent Google for flagging my site as duplicate content. I want to add a rel="alternate" code in my header:

For example:

```
In the Dutch website template:
<link href=”http://www.website.be/pagina-x/” hreflang=“nl-BE” rel=”alternate” />

In the Belgian website template:
<link href=”http://www.website.nl/pagina-x/” hreflang=“nl-NL” rel=”alternate” />
```

For that, i need to return the current page link, without the domainname. For example: /product/product-x.

```
<link href=”http://www.website.be/[current-url]” hreflang=“nl-BE” rel=”alternate” />
```

How do i do this?

I'm using Opencart 1.5.5.1 and seo url's set to yes and seo pack pro

Comment: You can use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to get the current url (without domainname)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to get the current url (without domainname).